# Duda quitar extensión en url web page

Tags: php, html, web, .htaccess

Hola he estado intentando quitar las extensiones de mis archivos en mi web page, pero solo funcionan con dos archivos.

que es lo que podría estar pasando? todos los archivos que manejos son extensión .php, leí por ahí que en el archivo .htaccess es donde debe ir el código, este es el código que tengo. Espero me puedan ayudar.

PD; tengo alojada mi pagina en un webhost gratuito para ser exactos 000webhost, yo pienso que este podría ser tal vez el problema, ha y un cosa mas tengo algunos archivos en carpetas no se si este sea también algún factor.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscás es lo siguiente:

**Código .htaccess para esconder la extensiones .php y .html**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
#RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ $1.php [NC] agrega / al final de url php


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
#RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ $1.html [NC] agrega / al final de url html
```